# Can anyone tell me how to Stream from a HTTPS (note the S) video source on Android

Tags: android, video, https, streaming

Can anyone tell me how to **Stream** from a **HTTPS** (note the S) video source on Android?!

```
VideoView mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoplayback_videoView);
... 
Uri videouri = Uri.parse("https://myvideo.mp4");
  mVideoView.setVideoURI(videouri);
  mVideoView.start();
```

This type of approach does not work. If i remove the "S" it works.

Comment: What is the reasoning for using https vs http?? It's video, it does not really need to be encrypted. Also, maybe the video encoder does not support video from https. I do not think it is possible.

Comment: Well the client i am doing this for requires everything to be secure especially video. I have been able to save the video and then read it off the sd card then it works but it needs to be streaming..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sorry but the current data sources supported by the Android Media Framework don't include HTTPS. That is the reason because it is working using HTTP but not with HTTPS.

From Android 3.0, and I suppose it will also be included in Android 2.4, there will be a DRM framework that will allow you to include your own DRM plugins to protect your streaming content. But you need to wait for it....

Comment: Thanks for the info do you mind telling me where you found that information?

Comment: You can find more information about DRM plugin framework at http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-3.0-highlights.html#multimedia. 

About supported protocols in the media framework, my source of information is the android source code. Regarding networking, only a handler for HTTP protocol is implemented.

Answer (score 1):

HTTPS for media seems to be not supported until Android 3.1 - http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

I think I managed to somehow make it work on a couple of Android 2.3 devices, but only when HTTPS video was served from the same server on which the host HTML resided (maybe browser was somehow reusing the SSL connection).